# A clarification about ConcurrentHashMap javadoc

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency

It's not very clear to me the last bit of the following quote:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset. **For aggregate operations such as putAll and
>   clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only
>   some entries.**

Why for only some entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and last parts must be read together to make sense. Breaking it down, we get that:

- Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so they may overlap with update operations
- Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset

Now, consider what happens in the case of `putAll` (this is the ConcurrentHashMap.java source):

```
for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet())
    put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Notice it adds each entry to the map in a loop. If you call `putAll` with 100 entries, and 50% of the way through, another thread attempts to `get` a value from the map, only 50 of the entries given to `putAll` will be available at that time.

Specifically: the documentation is not informing you that *specific* entries will not be available, just that the entire aggregate operation *may not be complete* before you call `get` in another thread, as they are not synchronized with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Only "some" of the changes may be seen  because another thread may access the map *during* the `putAll()` or `clear()`, which both require many steps to complete, when it's only *part* completed.

Answer (score 0):

`putAll` and `clear` aren't atomic operations. So if one threads calls `putAll` to put a couple of entries and another threads retrieves values in parallel, it may see an intermediate state of the `putAll` operation. The map doesn't block until the `putAll` method has completed. (Same for clearing - values can be retrieved *while* the clear operation is running in parallel).